# Bloc widgets reftech data (rebuild) when navigating to another pageView or any View altogether

Tags: flutter, widget, bloc

**Context:** I have an App that has a `PageView` to navigate between five screens using `BottomNavigationBar`, One page is making use of the Bloc Pattern (almost all of the pages will use Bloc in future releases) these Blocs are fetching data from backend service in filling the UI with the fetched data.

**Problem:** When navigating between pages at any level of the widget tree. the Bloc widget 'reset' and refetch the data from the repository.

As shown in the picture below:

[image: Screenshot that shows the problem]

Widget tree  as follows:

- main.dart

  - home.dart

    - timeline.dart (screen shown in the screenshot)

**Tried-Solutions:** I added the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to the page class and to other pages but it didn't do the job.

Here is the code for the build method for the page shown in the above screenshot

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    super.build(context);

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: _builAppBarWithTabs(),
        body: Center(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 1200),
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 800,
                    child: CustomScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverToBoxAdapter(
                          child: MasonryGrid(
                            column: getResponsiveColumnNumber(context, 1, 2, 6),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              // First Bloc
                              BlocProvider(
                                create: (context) {
                                  BrandBloc(repository: _brandRepository);
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 200,
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  height: 80,
                                  child: BrandScreen(
                                    brandBloc: context.bloc(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              CategoryScreen(
                                // Second Bloc
                                categoryBloc: CategoryBloc(
                                  repository: context.repository(),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 200,
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                height: 330,
                                child: _buildFeaturedItemsList(),
                              ),
                              Placeholder(
                                strokeWidth: 0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),


              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[here](https://pastebin.com/jVGXXf9a) is the code for class `timeline.dart`

[here](https://pastebin.com/cQU9juD8) is the code for class `home.dart` that contains the `BottomNavigationBar` class

**Question:** How to stop the blocs from fetching the data each time the widget rebuilds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got my head around the problem
As it turned out, it was not about the `bloc` as much it was a problem related to `PageView`.

I wrapped the `PageView` with `PageStorage` widget as follows:

```
final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket(); //PageStorageBucket
  static List<Widget> pages = [
    Timeline(pageController: pageController, key: PageStorageKey('timeline')),
    Search(key: PageStorageKey('search')),
    LikeScreen(key: PageStorageKey('like')),
    CartScreen(key: PageStorageKey('cart')),
    storageService.getFromDisk('api_token') != null
        ? ProfileScreen(key: PageStorageKey('profile'))
        : AuthChooserScreen(key: PageStorageKey('auth')),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return SafeArea(
      top: true,
      bottom: true,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        //Wrapped  PageView with PageStorage
        body: PageStorage(
          bucket: bucket,
          child: PageView(
            children: pages,
            controller: pageController,
            onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomNavigationBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Every page is assigned a PageStorageKey which is used to save and restore values that can outlive the widget

Thanks to this great medium article which explains it perfectly: 
[Keeping State with the Bottom Navigation Bar in Flutter](http://medium.com/@lucassaltoncardinali/keeping-state-with-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-69e4168878e1)

Answer (score 4):

You are using BlocProvider widget in a wrong way
Instead, you should extract the BlocProvider to the upper level which is not rebuilt while navigating between pages "maby to MaterialApp widget if you are using this bloc across your app".
Then use BlocBuilder or BlocConsumer to provide existing Bloc instance to the child widget and auto rebuild when bloc state change.
BlocBuilder official doc:
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocbuilder

Answer (score 1):

I was a stuck on a very similar problem here. In my case, I found the BlocProviders or Cubits needed to be managed outside the widget tree, and then using `BlocProvider.value` to insert them into it.

```
List<Widget> _pages = List.empty(growable: true);
List<Cubit> _cubits = List.empty(growable: true);

@override
void dispose() {
    _cubits.forEach((cubit) {
      cubit.close();
    });
    super.dispose();
}

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();    
    addPage(DateTime.now());
}

void addPage(DateTime day) {    
    MyCubit cubit = MyCubit(day: day)..load();
    _cubits.add(cubit);
    pages.add(BlocProvider<MyCubit>.value(
      value: cubit,
      child: MyPage(),
    ));
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(        
        body: PageView(
          controller: _controller,          
          children: _pages,
        ));
}
```

All credit and gratitude to this [github issue](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2118).